# jQuery get reference to object loaded in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

from jQuery, I load a web page inside a div in my page:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {      
        url = 'http://www.ansa.it/';
        $("#box")
            .html('<object data=' + url + '/>');
```

What can I do to get a reference to an element loaded in this div?
Example:

```
$('#IDToken1').val("CCCC");
```

Doesn't work. What can I do to access the element with id 'IDToken1' loaded from  http://www.ansa.it in my div with id 'box'?
Thanks in advance
Max

Answer (score 0):

You cannot when you use `OBJECT` to embed the document. You could use an `IFRAME` instead.

> An embedded document is only rendered within another document (e.g.,
>   in a subwindow); it remains otherwise independent.

Reference: https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/objects.html#h-13.5

Comment: I cannot use IFRAME because for example google site doesn't work in IFRAME, any other workaround?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to use a GET request.

```
$(document).ready(function () {      
    url = 'http://www.ansa.it/';
    $.get( url, function( data ) {
        $( "#box" ).html( data );
    });
});
```